# Why this code does not find the Key STATUS (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
$ar_alles_fertig = array();

foreach ($ar_fertig as $key => $value) {

    if (($value["DONE"] == 0) && ($value["INWORK"] == 1)) {

        $ar_alles_fertig[$key] = "Alle Noch nicht bearbeitet (Probenstatus:0)";
        $ar_alles_fertig[$key]["STATUS"] = "0";
    }
    if (($value["DONE"] == 1) && ($value["INWORK"] == 1)) {
        $ar_alles_fertig[$key] = "einige bearbeitet (Probenstatus:1)";
        $ar_alles_fertig[$key]["STATUS"] = "1";
    }
    if (($value["DONE"] == 1) && ($value["INWORK"] == 0)) {
        $ar_alles_fertig[$key] = "alle bearbeitet (Probenstatus:2)";
        $ar_alles_fertig[$key]["STATUS"] = "2";
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'STATUS' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 49

what is wrong?

Comment: Because you define `$ar_alles_fertig[$key]` as a string and then you attempt to access it as an array.

Comment: Maybe `$ar_alles_fertig[$key]['MESSAGE']="Alle Noch nicht bearbeitet (Probenstatus:0)";` or something. etc...

Answer (score 1):

Here you set value as string

```
$ar_alles_fertig[$key]="einige bearbeitet (Probenstatus:1)";
```

And now try to use it as array

```
$ar_alles_fertig[$key]["STATUS"]="1";
```

Replace it with smth like

```
 $ar_alles_fertig[$key]["MESSAGE"] ="einige bearbeitet (Probenstatus:1)";
 $ar_alles_fertig[$key]["STATUS"]="1";
```